# Is there a way to change the property of a Windows.Forms.Label from a event handler in which the Label is not created in?

Tags: c#, multithreading, cefsharp

I had created a Panel that contains a Label and a CefSharp instance. The panel is then added to the WinForms. The purpose of the label is to show something before the browser finishes loading. Once the browser finished loading, I want the visible property of the label to be false.

But I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid:
> Control 'Loading' accessed from a thread other than the thread it
> was created on.'

How can I solve it?

This is the method that creates all the controls.

```
chromeBrowser = new CustomWebBrowser("https://www.google.com/");
chromeBrowser.FrameLoadEnd += OnBrowserFrameLoadEnd;
Panel panel = new Panel()
        {
            Name = "Container",
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            BackColor = Color.Aquamarine,
            Padding = new Padding(5),
            Margin = new Padding(2),
        };

        Label label = new Label
        {
            Name = "Loading",
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            BackColor = Color.Black,
            ForeColor = Color.White,
            Padding = new Padding(5),
            Margin = new Padding(2),
        };

        // Add reference
        chromeBrowser.Label = label;

        panel.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
        panel.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser.Label);
        panel.Controls.SetChildIndex(chromeBrowser.Label, 0);

        //Add the browser to the Form 
        this.Controls.Add(panel);
```

The OnBrowserFrameLoadEnd event handler

```
private void OnBrowserFrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs args)
        {
            CustomWebBrowser wb = (CustomWebBrowser)sender;

            if(wb.Label != null)
            {
                wb.Label.Visible = false;
                MessageBox.Show("Done");
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Sinatr Yes, it does solve my problem. Thank You very much. Another question, do you know where can I learn more about threading?

Comment: Read [books](http://www.albahari.com/threading/), do mistakes and solve them.